# What is the difference between phonology and phonetics?

Tags: meaning

Could someone explain briefly, with some examples?

Comment: To start with, it's _phonetics_. With an "E". Now that you know how to spell both words, try looking them up in Wikipedia. Oh, and, no, no one can explain briefly. It's like discussing the difference between differential and integral calculus; a brief explanation is not available.

Comment: You might get some better answers if you ask this in the "linguistics" forum. But I agree: first you need to learn what a phoneme is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Phonetics deals with the production of speech sounds by humans, often without prior knowledge of the language being spoken. Phonology is about patterns of sounds, especially different patterns of sounds in different languages, or within each language, different patterns of sounds in different positions in words etc.

Phonology as grammar of phonetic patterns

```
The consonant cluster /st/ is OK at the beginning, middle or end of words in English.
At beginnings of words, /str/ is OK in English, but /ftr/ or /tr/ are not (they are ungrammatical).
/tr/ is OK in the middle of words, however, e.g. in "ashtray".
/tr/ is OK at the beginnings of words in German, though, and /ftr/ is OK word-initially in Russian, but not in English or German.
```

Comment: Lots of English words begin with /tr/. Just look in a dictionary. But none of this has anything to do with phonetics and phonology. A very poor answer in fact.

Comment: I just tried to explain the base consept

Comment: Yes, but you got it all wrong.

Comment: @fdb I don't think so!!!  Have you read my answer???

Comment: Yes, and I even commented on it.

Comment: @fdb I love you!

Comment: @AliRashidi Your masochistic tendencies aside . . . Your answer *is* wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Phonetics** studies all the various sounds that people say.

**Phonology** studies the sound systems of a language. This usually involves building a model of the various **phonemes** of each language.

For example, here are the various vowel sounds found around the world:

[image]

Because vowels are formed by the position of the tongue there are no strict divisions between the sounds. So there would be vowel sounds between the ones which have been labelled. Phonetics would be interested in saying where exactly a particular vowel fits on the chart. Phonology would try to then figure out how many vowel phonemes there are in each language. A simple language might have three: i, u and a. They would be the base sounds, but in casual speech you would hear people say vowels that are slightly different.

For consonants, there are many liquid consonant sounds - sounds like l and r. Phonetics would be interested in looking how exactly each of them are made. Phonology is interested in how many are considered distinct sounds in a language. Many Asian languages only have one liquid consonant so that l and r are interchangeable without any difference of meaning.